# Service account exists but error occurs of " service account kube-lego/kube-lego2-kube-lego was not found, retry after the service account is created"

Tags: kubernetes

Output of `kubectl get serviceaccounts | rg lego`:

```
kube-lego2-kube-lego   1         21h
```

However,

Output of `kubectl get events --all-namespaces | rg kube-lego2`:

```
kube-lego   5m         20h         67        kube-lego-7c66c7fddf         ReplicaSet                                Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset-controller                         Error creating: pods "kube-lego-7c66c7fddf-" is forbidden: service account kube-lego/kube-lego2-kube-lego was not found, retry after the service account is created
```

Why am I getting this error? Is it due the `kube-lego/` prefix? Why is that there?

Maybe something to do with the namespace?

---

Output of `kubectl get deployment --namespace=kube-lego kube-lego -o yaml --export`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "4"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"kube-lego","namespace":"kube-lego"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"kube-lego"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"LEGO_LOG_LEVEL","value":"debug"},{"name":"LEGO_EMAIL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"lego.email","name":"kube-lego"}}},{"name":"LEGO_URL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"lego.url","name":"kube-lego"}}},{"name":"LEGO_NAMESPACE","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}},{"name":"LEGO_POD_IP","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"status.podIP"}}}],"image":"jetstack/kube-lego:master-4209","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"kube-lego","ports":[{"containerPort":8080}],"readinessProbe":{"httpGet":{"path":"/healthz","port":8080},"initialDelaySeconds":5,"timeoutSeconds":1}}]}}}}
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: kube-lego
  name: kube-lego
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-lego/deployments/kube-lego
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kube-lego
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: kube-lego
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: LEGO_LOG_LEVEL
          value: debug
        - name: LEGO_EMAIL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: lego.email
              name: kube-lego
        - name: LEGO_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: lego.url
              name: kube-lego
        - name: LEGO_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: LEGO_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        image: jetstack/kube-lego:master-4209
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: kube-lego
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: kube-lego2-kube-lego
      serviceAccountName: kube-lego2-kube-lego
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe something to do with the namespace?

- Yes, ServiceAccount is namespaced resource. You have to have ServiceAccount in same namespace that you reference it from for this to work. By what I gather here your ServiceAccount `kube-lego2-kube-lego` is in `default` namespace while it should be present in `kube-lego`.